# jQuery: event.preventdefault not working with Firefox (mac and PC)

Tags: jquery, firefox, toggle, preventdefault

I have this bit of jQuery toggling a paragraph after an H3 link. It works in IE and Chrome on PC and Safari and Chrome on Mac. On Firefox on both platforms, clicking the link does nothing at all?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rightcolumn .article .collapse").hide();
$("#rightcolumn h3 a").click(function(){
if(event.preventDefault){
event.preventDefault();
}else{
event.returnValue = false; 
};
$(this).parent().next().toggle(400);
});
});
</script>
```

If I disable the event.preventDefault(); section it works in Firefox, but of course then I get the page jumping to the top which I don't want. What can I do to get it working in Firefox?

Comment: try `event.stopPropagation()` as well

Comment: @Thomas: Irrelevant whether it propagates or not. The problem is that he's not declaring the function argument, and so on non-IE browsers, calling *anything* on `event` throws an exception as `event` is not defined. See Nicky's answer.

Comment: @T.J yeah, you're right. i'd forgotten what stopProgagation actually meant as it had helped me with some obscure issues. thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 16):

You are missing the event declaration from your function.  Also as a convention I see most examples using evt as the variable name.

```
$("#rightcolumn h3 a").click(function(evt)
{
   evt.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().next().toggle(400);
}
```

Comment from T.J. Crowder as to including the evt in function()

> You need to declare the parameter to the click handler (event is not a global except on IE and browsers that throw a bone to IE-specific websites.) And note that you don't need (or want) the test for preventDefault. jQuery supplies it on browsers that don't provide it natively

More explanation on [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: With this kind of answer, I recommend *telling* them what you changed, as well as the example. @Andy: You need to declare the parameter to the `click` handler (`event` is not a global except on IE and browsers that throw a bone to IE-specific websites.) And note that you don't need (or want) the test for `preventDefault`. jQuery supplies it on browsers that don't provide it natively.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder good point I was just about to rush out the door here.  I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Nicky! Works perfectly. Thanks for your prompt reply. :)

Comment: No problem. I was in a bit of a rush earlier so I'll update my answer with T.J.'s explanation of why that was required.  Also if you're happy with the solution it is good etiquette to mark it as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the Event parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rightcolumn .article .collapse").hide();
$("#rightcolumn h3 a").click(function(event){
if(event.preventDefault){
event.preventDefault();
}else{
event.returnValue = false; 
};
$(this).parent().next().toggle(400);
});
});
</script>
```

This question already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712808

Note how the handler in the docs show this eventObject as the parameter passed to it: http://api.jquery.com/click/

And note how the Event object has the preventDefault method: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/