# Both event.preventDefault() and event.returnValue = false don't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, return-value, preventdefault

I have tried these to snippets of codes, the first one works in IE and Chrome, the second one works in Chrome only, but both of them don't work in Firefox. What I want is to stop the page from going to other pages via links

```
$('.album a').click(function(){
    event.returnValue = false;
    //other codes
})

$('.album a').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    //other codes
})
```

Edit:
This snippet from Ian worked for me

```
$('.album a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //other codes
});
```

Comment: You might consider not using a-links, particularly as you are not using them as links. You can use another element (span, etc.) and, if you want to, use css to make it look like a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide the `Event` parameter:

```
$('.album a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //other codes
});
```

You don't need to deal with `returnValue`, as jQuery normalizes the method to work across browsers, by only calling `preventDefault`.

Note how the handler in the docs show this `eventObject` as the parameter passed to it: http://api.jquery.com/click/

And note how the `Event` object has the `preventDefault` method: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 2):

Your callback signature does not register the `event` argument. Therefor your callbacks do not have access to the `event` object, and cannot prevent it.

```
$('.album a').click(function(event){
    event.returnValue = false;
    //other codes
});

$('.album a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //other codes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to the following:

```
$('.album a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```